# routes not render the content of Register component and Login component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i did routes of my social chat app with react v6, so the app component display their content but the other ones(Register component and Login component) didn't show me its own content, i have no idea how to fix this problem. this is my code:

```
enter code here
```

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import MatchPath from "./utils";
import React from 'react';


function App() {
  return (
    <Router >
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
      <Route path="" element={<Landing />} />
      <Route path="" element={
        <div className="container">
          <Route path="register" element={< Register/>} />
          <Route path="login" element={< Login/>} />

        </div>
      } ></Route>
      </Routes>
        
        
       
      
      
      <Footer />
   </div>
   </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Register extends Component {
render() {
return (

## Register

```
  </div>
)
```

}
}

export default Register;

import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Login extends Component {
render() {
return (

## Login

## Login

## Login

## Login

## Login

)
}
}

export default Login;

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Navbar extends Component {
render() {
return (


DevConnector

```
    <div className ="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobile-nav">
      <ul className ="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li className ="nav-item">
          <Link className ="nav-link" to="/profiles"> Developers
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul className ="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li className ="nav-item">
          <Link className ="nav-link" to="register">Sign Up</Link>
        </li>
        <li className ="nav-item">
          <Link className ="nav-link" to="login">Login</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
)
```

}
}

export default Navbar;

Comment: why your path is empty ? and why you did not use path as exact

Comment: Check path. You have empty("") path for Landing component as well as container for register and login.

Comment: path="register" write this as exact path="/register"

Comment: i write the path like this path="/register" for Register component and  path="/login" for Login component with "exact" in advance and i did path="/" for landing component.  the login  and register page  are the same except the landing page is different